# can't see the left sidebar on Trello

Tags: trello

Can't see the left sidebar on Trello. 
I just started using Trello, and had a left sidebar where I could see a list of names I've given the lists in my active board, but some reason is not showing anymore.

I only see the right sidebar, but not the left.

Comment: Could you maybe add screen shots?

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if the left sidebar was removed with the big update yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

The sidebars on Trello can be shown and hidden. Hover your mouse over the left edge, and you should it light up and a little disclosure triangle appear about halfway down. Click and the sidebar should return. You can collapse it (and probably did by accident) by doing the same just past the edge of the sidebar.